# How do I make UL LI in absolutely positioned container hover properly?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list in an absolutely positioned div. I am attempting to make a hover effect on the individual li elements and it is simply not working. The cursor only triggers the hover effect when it is quite a bit above the text of the li.

This is the widest segment of a responsive design layout and the hover works just fine until the widest state when, for design concerns I have to switch the containing div to position absolute and I have ran many experiments and it always works without absolute positioning but I simply cannot position my container properly in the final state with removing it from the flow.

This one is driving me nuts, where am I going wrong??

```
.secondary_header{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position:absolute;
    width:700px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:60px;
    height:60px;
}   

.secondary_header ul{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}

.secondary_header ul li{
    background-image:url(../images/audio_icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px;
    padding-left:50px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    line-height:60px;
    padding-left:50px;
    height:60px;

}

.secondary_header ul li:hover{
   color:#09F;
}
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or html code as well?

Comment: please post more code or fiddle looks like the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I changed the z-index of the secondary_header div and the problem was solved. Not sure what to post to make the question more useful!

Answer (score 0):

The Information You provided is not enough. If the following code meets your requirement then be happy or else .. elaborate your requirement so that I can have a good idea.

```
.secondary_header{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position:absolute;
    width:700px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:60px;
    height:60px;
}   

.secondary_header ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
}

.secondary_header ul li{
    background-image:url(../images/audio_icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px;
    padding:0 15px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    line-height:60px;
    height:60px;
    cursor:pointer;

}

.secondary_header ul li:hover{
   color:#09F;
}
```